# Size doesn't increase, yet it stores larger data. How is this possible?

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

I was trying this code in gcc6.3:

```
char a[2];
char b[]="Aditya";
strcpy(a,b);
printf("%s %lu\n",a,sizeof(a));
```

the output was:

```
aditya@aditya-Gateway-series:~/luc$ ./a
Aditya 2
```

How can variable a be still 2 bytes big and store an information of 7bytes?

Comment: Take a piece of paper, and write something on it that is too big for the paper, so the remaining text is written on the table instead. The text didn't fit on the paper, yet you can still read it. That's about what happens in your code.

Comment: @Blaze Nice example.. :)

Comment: @Blaze Yes, nice. @Aditya try printing `b` this may give you some insight on how you messed the "table".

Comment: Where did you read about auto array size expansion in C? If there is a such a place on internet - add it to the blocked sites, if it is a book - bin it.

Comment: @kmkaplan a bit of warning: Don't rely on the outcome, either. A program having UB, can do anything, including, "working as expected".....

Comment: @P__J__ Thanks for bringing in that angle, added a bit in the answer to address that.

Comment: @Blaze A bit of warning though...if you submit that paper to the examiner ... I'm not sure how many marks you'll get. :P

Comment: @SouravGhosh that's right, and it showcases exactly what the problem is. We can read the text and everything seems to be working fine, but suddenly we get bad marks. And when we wrote on the table, half of it actually went on a different paper lying next to that paper, and now that other paper's content is destroyed and someone else will get angry at us for ruining it.

Comment: @Blaze You sir, remind me of my college days. :)

Answer (score 4):

In your code:

```
strcpy(a,b);
```

invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're trying to access memory which is not valid. Don't rely on the outcome.

To elaborate, `a` has only storage to hold two `char`s, if you try to write (here, to copy) more than a single-char string (with the null-terminator), you'll overrrun the allocated memory, thereby venturing into invalid memory location.

The source buffer of `strcpy()`, `b` has more content that can be fit into the destination buffer `a`, thus the operation involves boundary overrun. It's the job of the programmer to ensure that the destination buffer has sufficient memory.

---

That said, regarding the size calculation - let me add, array size, once defined, cannot be changed. You can chose to fill up the contents of leave them unitialized / unused, but arrays, once defined, cannot be resized.

Answer (score 1):

As Sourav Ghosh said, your usage of `strcpy` is incorrect and induces undefined behavior. What I think happens is that `a` is of size 2, `b` is ob size 7, and they happen to be placed next to each other in the memory, resulting in 9 bytes of continuous allocated memory. So after copy, `a` is still of size 2, and holds `"Ad"` - however printing it displays the whole string as the print continues until first end-of-string character. If you print `b`, I think you'll get `"itya"`, as its adress is located 2 bytes next to a.
I hope this is clear enough and it helps !

Comment: Maybe...could be...possibly....but end of the day, it's undefined. Nothing you can do to prove that the outcome can be predicted universally.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I agree of course ! That was just an hypothesis on what happened on this special case.

Answer (score 1):

`a` only contains `{'A', 'd'}` - the remaining characters are written to the memory *after* `a`.  In your case, you didn’t write over anything important, so the code appears to function as expected.

*Appears* to.  The behavior of writing past the end of an array is *undefined*, meaning there’s no requirement on the compiler or runtime environment to handle the situation in any particular way.  C does not require a bounds check on array accesses - it won’t throw an exception if you write past the end of an array.  Your code *may* crash immediately, you *may* wind up with corrupted data, it *may* leave your program in a bad state such that it crashes later (those situations are fun to debug, let me tell you), or it may work with no apparent problems.

It is up to you, the programmer, to make sure the target array is large enough to hold the new value.  The language doesn’t protect you at all here.